# What cell SHOULD this formula produce?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, formulas

I am using this formula (I didn't copy and paste it from somewhere, hence it doesn't work)

```
=VLOOKUP($AD$5,Data_Sheet!A$1:L$499,MATCH(I23,Data_Sheet!$C$3:$L$3,0),FALSE)
```

If the following cells have the following values

```
AD5 = Tiger (which is in row 26 of Data_Sheet i.e A28)
A1:L499 = my data
I23 = Africa (which is cell C3 in Data_Sheet)
C3:L3 = all the countries(including Africa)
```

What should the formula produce? I am intending the formula to find (what I know should be) cell C28 but instead it returns A28!

Comment: Because it will produce a relative number the columns in `Data_Sheet!$C$3:$L$3` need to match the columns in `Data_Sheet!A$1:L$499`.  So make it `MATCH(I23,Data_Sheet!$A$3:$L$3,0)`

Comment: Scott you are a god! I've been staring at it for about 45 minutes now. Thank you. If you'd like, you can put that as the answer so I can give you the credit you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it will produce a relative number the columns in `Data_Sheet!$C$3:$L$3` need to match the columns in `Data_Sheet!A$1:L$499`.

So make it:

```
MATCH(I23,Data_Sheet!$A$3:$L$3,0)
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help Scott, I'll accept the answer when it lets me in 6 mins :)